# The use of next() in middlewares

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I'm new to programming and I've been following Colt Steele's web developer bootcamp and was trying to create a simple blog app. I've attached the entire code but the part that I'd like to focus on is

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
req.session.redirectTo = req.originalUrl;
res.redirect("/login");}
```

In this case, I'm trying to use the middleware isLoggedIn to check whether the user is logged only after which she can add a new album or blog post. But on clicking, add new album if the user IS logged in, it takes me back to the login page.

After some research I tried to store the req.originalUrl  inside req.session.returnTo . This should store the URL of the users GET request anywhere we use the middleware.

and the login route is as follows

```
//handling login logic
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate("local", 
    {
    failureRedirect: "/login"
}), (req, res) => { 
    let returnTo = req.session.returnTo ? req.session.returnTo : '/albums'
    delete req.session.returnTo;   
    res.redirect(returnTo);
})
```

Here I removed successRedirect from the Passport object so I don't redirect prematurely and handled the redirect to req.session.returnTo in the callback.

My main assumption was that next() would run the res.render, but it doesn't seem to and I cannot figure out why.

```
const express            = require('express'),
      app                = express(),
      mongoose           = require('mongoose'),
      bodyParser         = require('body-parser'),
      expressSanitizer   = require('express-sanitizer'),
      methodOverride     = require('method-override'),
      passport           = require('passport'),
      LocalSrategy       = require('passport-local'),
      User               = require('./models/users');

//APP CONFIG          
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://arya123:password1234567890@crudclust-gc08c.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority', { 
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('Connected to DB!')
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('ERROR', err.message);
    })

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(expressSanitizer());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

//PASSPORT CONFIG
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: "Nico wins cutest dog!",
    resave: false,
    saveUnititialized: false,
    cookie: { secure: true }
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalSrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.serializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

//MODEL CONFIG
let cataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    artist: String,
    body: String,
    art: String
});

let Catalog = mongoose.model('Catalog', cataSchema);

// let George = new Catalog ({
//     title: "All things must pass",
//     artist: "George Harrison",
//     body: "This is an album"
// });
// George.save();


//ROUTES
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/albums');
});

app.get('/albums', (req, res) => {
        Catalog.find({}, function(err, catalogs){
            if(err){
                console.log("ERROR!");
            } else {
               res.render("index", {catalogs: catalogs}); 
            }
        });
}); 

//NEW ALBUM
app.get('/albums/new', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    res.render("new");
});

//POST ROUTE
app.post('/albums', (req, res) =>  {
    console.log(req.body);
    Catalog.create(req.body.catalog, (err, newCatlog) => {
        if(err){
            res.render('/albums/new');
        }
        else{
            res.redirect('/albums');
        }
    });
});

//SHOW
app.get('/albums/:id', (req, res) =>{
    Catalog.findById(req.params.id, (err, foundCatalog) => {
        if(err){
            res.redirect('/albums');
        }
        else{
            res.render('show', {catalog: foundCatalog});
        }
    });
});

//EDIT
app.get('/albums/:id/edit', (req, res) => {
    Catalog.findById(req.params.id, (err, foundCatalog) => {
        if(err){
            res.redirect('/albums');
        }
        else{
            res.render('edit', {catalog: foundCatalog})
        }
    });
});

//UPDATE ROUTE
app.put('/albums/:id', (req, res) => {
    req.body.catalog.body = req.sanitize(req.body.catalog.body);
    console.log(req.body.catalog);
    console.log(req.params.id);
    console.log("===================")
    Catalog.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.catalog, (err, updated) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            console.log("===============");
            res.redirect('/albums');
        }
        else{
            res.redirect("/albums/"+ req.params.id);
        }
    });
});

//DELETE ROUTE
app.delete('/albums/:id' , (req, res) => {
    Catalog.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err, removed) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            console.log(req.params.body);
            console.log("==============");
            res.redirect('/albums');
        }
        else{
            res.redirect('/albums');
        }
    });
});

//===========
//AUTH ROUTES
//===========

//Show register form
app.get('/register',(req, res) => {
    res.render('register');
})

//SIGN UP
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    let newUser = new User({username: req.body.username});
    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, (err, user) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.redirect("register")
        }
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, () => {
            res.redirect('/albums')
        })
    })
   
});

//SHOW LOGIN
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    res.render('login')
})
//handling login logic
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate("local", 
    {
    failureRedirect: "/login"
}), (req, res) => { 
    let returnTo = req.session.returnTo ? req.session.returnTo : '/albums'
    delete req.session.returnTo;   
    res.redirect(returnTo);
})

//LOGOUT ROUTE
app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect("/albums")
})

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return next();
        }
    req.session.redirectTo = req.originalUrl;
    res.redirect("/login");
}

//PORT
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`Now listening on Port: ${port}`);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So what does `next()` do?

if you hit a route like this

```
app.post("/login", auth, middleware1, middleware2, middleware3, lastMiddleware);
```

I have here alot of middlewares. You need to know that your request always goes from the left middleware to right.

That means you start with the `auth` middleware.

Lets assume you are done with `auth` and you want to continue to the next middleware `middleware1` how do you do that?

For this you need `next()`. It will jump to the next middlware to `middleware1`.

If you want to jump to the next middleware then use `next()` again and again.

So lets assume you are on the last middleware, and usually you send an response back to the user. But what happens if you dont send an response back and use `next()`?

You kinda "jump out" of your current route `app.post("/login")` and your request checks the other routes if it matches he requested route.
Usually no route will match and you should land on `404` error page witch is usually defined at the end of your server script. Could look like this

```
app.use(function() {
   res.send("Error cannot find")
})
```